# Change Model values after load in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In my mongoose model, I have some `stats` that are dependent on time. My idea is to add a [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to change these stats right after the model has been loaded.

Unfortunately, the documentation on the `post`-Hooks is a bit lacking in clarity. It seems like I can use a hook like this:

```
schema.post('init', function(doc) {
    doc.foo = 'bar';
    return doc;
});
```

Their only examples involve `console.log`-outputs. It does not explain in any way if the `doc` has to be returned or if a change in the post-Hook is impossible at all (since it is not asynchronous, there might be little use for complex ideas).

If the `pre` on `'init'` is not the right way to automatically update a model on load, then what is?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is how we update models on load, working asynchronously:

```
schema.pre('init', function(next, data) {
  data.property = data.property || 'someDefault';
  next();
});
```

Pre-init is special, the other hooks have a slightly different signature, for example pre-save:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.accessed_ts = Date.now();
  next();
});
```

Comment: So pre-init is actually after the data is loaded? And the document is not in the `this` context?

Comment: Pre-init is after the data is loaded, but *before* the document is hydrated with that data (afaik). Since the data has not been placed in the document yet, the "this" context exists (it's still the doc) but it will be empty (iirc).