# Mongoose - Post Hook - Change Doc/Model values after load & Before Returning

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Solved: I can only guess that delirium got me.**

*sorry for not figuring it out before posting, but here's the solution for the next persons sake. The try/catch is not necessary, but it did help me get out some errors that were not being printed to console. If there is a better way to document solving my own problem, I'd appreciate the feedback.*

**Old Question**

I have docs stored in my mongo db that I want to modify before being returned to a find() or findOne(). I want to do this without changing the values and a single hook for all find variants. Call it a masking. I'm actually normalizing a numeric value to a scale of 0 to 1. I do not want to modify the value in the doc, just change the values when the doc is returned via find, findOne. E.G. "Change Model values after load in Mongoose"

**Solution**

```
schema.post('init', function(doc){
  try{
    console.log(doc); // prints the doc to console, complete
    doc.property = "new property value"; // changes the document value
    console.log(doc); // returns the modified document
    return doc;
  }
  catch(error){
     console.log(error);
  } 
}
```

**Old Notes**

Other threads note usage of the post init hook. I have tried the methods in the following related topics with no success.

[Mongoose - how to tap schema middleware into the 'init' event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221368/mongoose-how-to-tap-schema-middleware-into-the-init-event)

[Change Model values after load in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693523/change-model-values-after-load-in-mongoose) (this method has changed with 5.x)

```
schema.post('init', function(doc){
   console.log('Tell me i fired'); // works, prints to console
   console.log(doc); // works, prints full model to console
   doc.valueField = doc.valueField2+doc.valueField3; // fails, no doc returned, throws no errors
});

schema.post('init', function(doc, next){
   console.log('Tell me i fired'); // works, prints to console
   console.log(doc); // works, prints full model to console
   doc.valueField1 = doc.valueField2+doc.valueField3; // fails, no doc returned, throws no errors
   next();
});
```

I've tried adding return(doc);, doc.save() and just about every mutation of the above code I can compile in my shrinking mental capacity. I keep throwing crap at the wall and nothing is sticking. The [documentation over at mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) is poor and the behavior changed with version 5.x with the removal of Asynch call backs (dropped the next() ).

This is a bug submission on mongoose where the dropping of next() is noted.
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6037

release notes from the 5.x release
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/migrating_to_5.md#init-hook-signatures

~ Edited, because i solved my own problem ~

Comment: It is not clear what you want. *Change before it exits my API*, could mean many things.

Comment: Editing for clarification. Trying to fire the post(init) as noted in the documentation so as to modify the document before returning to a find search. This is reported to affect all variants of find.
'schema.post('init', function(doc) {
  console.log('%s has been initialized from the db', doc._id);
});'

Comment: Tried your solution, but didn't work for me, the regular document still got returned.